# I am using the following VBA macro to copy cells in excel. How could I amend it so that only vales are copied and not the format

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub ButtonCode()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim DestRow As Long
    Set ws1 = Sheets("RA REQUEST FORM")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("ACTIVE CREDITS")
    DestRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws1.Range("A22").Copy ws2.Range("A" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("D11").Copy ws2.Range("B" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("C18").Copy ws2.Range("E" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("C19").Copy ws2.Range("G" & DestRow)
```

Comment: `ws2.Range("A" & DestRow).Value = ws1.Range("A22").Value`... and so on.

Comment: Thanks but that gave me the following error:
runtime error 1004
copy method of range class failed

Comment: Never mind...this worked perfectly! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BigBen said, use the .value property of the range to copy just the value of the range.

```
Sub ButtonCode()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim DestRow As Long
    Set ws1 = Sheets("RA REQUEST FORM")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("ACTIVE CREDITS")
    DestRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws2.Range("A" & DestRow).value = ws1.Range("A22").value
    ws2.Range("B" & DestRow).value = ws1.Range("D11").value
    ws2.Range("E" & DestRow).value = ws1.Range("C18").value
    ws2.Range("G" & DestRow).value = ws1.Range("C19").value

End Sub
```

You also can use `ws1.Range("A22").Copy` and `ws2.Range("A" & DestRow).PasteSpecial xlValues` instead, but that's annoying because the code will then clear anything on your clipboard.

Comment: Appreciate that, thank you! Worked perfectly!!